# QWidget corner widths

Tags: qt, grid-layout, qwidget, qgridlayout

I have an application that holds a `QWidget` inside a `QMainWindow`. I have added `QGgridLayout` to add additonal `QWidgets` inside, but there is a border-like line which I want to dissapear. This line belongs to `QGridlayout`.

[image]

Comment: Layouts don't have borders.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: there is nothing in the code section.. I know layouts dont have borders but what is that ?

Comment: Could you show the widget tree?

Comment: http://s30.postimg.org/yvv416a5d/Untitled.png this is the widget tree @thuga

Comment: The borders come from the `QFrame` widget. You can change its frame shape to no frame. It's somewhere in the property list.

Comment: @thuga it is set to FrameShape:NoFrame, FrameShadow: Plain, linewidth:0

Comment: Then maybe it's one of the `QLabel` widgets. They also have frames. What is that widget in the middle?